# PDF java script resulting in “OFF” value in output field due to off state of check box

Tags: javascript, pdf, acrobat

For most part this script in this PDF form works fine, it checks if Check Box4 is checked and if it is, it results in a calculation of Level + Check Box4 thru 7 (on state off check boxes have a vaule of 2). The problem occurs that if any of Check Box5, 6 or 7 check boxes are in an off state, the calculatiuon returns the word "OFF" into the field as their output. The calculation still works in the end as this field is then part of a further calculation, but visibly this is bad.

This funciotn is used 35 times on the first page of the pdf alone

Advice on how to retreive the on value but ignore the off value of a check box would be appreciated.

```
<code>
var v1 = this.getField("Check Box4").value;
if (v1 /= "") {
   event.value = this.getField("Level").value
 + this.getField("Check Box4").value
 + this.getField("Check Box5").value
 + this.getField("Check Box6").value
 + this.getField("Check Box7").value; }
if (isNaN(v1) || v1 === "") {event.value = "0";}
</code>
```

[screen shot of resulting yuck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6awK.png)
[page screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnJct.png)

Answer (score 0):

One thing I do pretty often is replace the "Off" with something else, such as a space or even the empty string, as in:

```
this.getField("myCheckBox").valueAsString.replace(/Off/gim, "") ;
```

If your return values are non-numeric, you can use `value` instead of `valueAsString`.

And that should do it.